# Discrete simplicial set, definition

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

What is usually called a **discrete simplicial set**?

I know, though, what is a discrete topological space.

It is used [here](https://libgen.pw/download/book/5a1f04e83a044650f507e5bc),
on page 15, but never defined. They say on page xiv, that "the term space will be often used interchangeably for topological spaces or simplicial sets."

Answer (score 4):

A discrete simplicial set is a simplicial set with no nondegenerate simplices except in degree $0$.  Equivalently, it is a simplicial set in which all the face and degeneracy maps are isomorphisms, or a simplicial set which is isomorphic to the singular simplicial set of a discrete topological space, or a simplicial set which is isomorphic to a constant functor $\Delta^{op}\to \mathtt{Set}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer and **prove** equivalences (1)A discrete simplicial set is a simplicial set with no nondegenerate simplices except in degree 0. (2)  Equivalently, it is a simplicial set in which all the face and degeneracy maps are isomorphisms (3) simplicial set which is isomorphic to a constant functor $\Delta^{op}\to \mathtt{Set}$.